# How To Deploy From An Asp.Net Website

Tags: asp.net, windows-installer

Is it possible to run an msi installation file remotely from an Asp.Net web server?  I'd like to have a button labeled "download" where a visitor who browses to the web page and clicks the button can run an msi file to install a seperate windows application (in this case, a wpf application) onto their computer.  In the event that the installation is incomplete, I wouldn't want to leave the msi file lying around on their desktop or computer.  For some reason, every time I search for this information, I only find tutorials on deploying websites rather than how to deploy an application from a website.

Many thanks in advance!

Andrew

Comment: Would providing a link to the installable directly in your webpage be insufficient? Provided the logged in user has sufficient privileges on the machine, arent they able to run the installable? Thats usually how activex controls / add-ins etc get installed. Re - not having the installable lying around, the user always has the option to "Open" or "Save" the file and can do so if needed. Is that something you explicitly want to prevent?

Comment: @In Sane - Well, the idea to not have the installable lying around was for the sake of copy protection.  If the installable were able to be downloaded from the website, then it could be freely (although technically illegally) distributed.  I just wanted to prevent that.  Also, with respect to having a link to the installable on the website, that's an interesting idea...  I've never done that before in Asp.Net.  Could I do that with a Server.Transfer(virtualFilePathName) method call?  That's one thing I'm interested in but not sure about.

Answer (score 0):

Look into ClickOnce (though it's IE and firefox (with plugin) only).  Otherwise, if .Net is already installed and you can put everything in one executable, there's no installing needed.  The .exe file will just run.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I looked into ClickOnce, but it won't let you create a folder in the "Program Files" directory.  It will run the application on install, which is cool, since this would allow me to add extra one-time setup code to the application.  Plus, publishing with ClickOnce will create an .htm file that can be added to a website, which is pretty much what I'm looking for.  The only problem is that it doesn't offer as many customization options as an .msi (I don't think, anyway...).

Comment: Also, what do you mean when you say "The .exe will just run."?  Can I do something in asp.net like Server.Transfer(Server.MapPath(exeVirtualPath)) in order to cause it to execute on the browser's machine?  I've never done anything like that before, kinda new to this...

Comment: My bad, I don't know why I didn't understand what you said about the .exe file running.  It makes sense.  Still, is there a way to run a .msi file remotely from a website?  I guess there might not be ...